# Euler method for two dimension system

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am absolutely a beginner in programming. and trying to write an algorithm of the Euler method for interaction two systems. When I run the code I got this Error message. I will appreciate it if you help me. Thank you.

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
def NmDef(U1, V1, U2, V2):
    Nm = math.sqrt((U1-V1)**2+(U2-V2)**2)     #sqrt 
    return Nm

NmDef_value = []
for i in range(n):
    i +=1
    L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])
    print(i, L)
    NmDef_value.append(L)
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to dump all your code here and expect people to fix it for free. You need to put in some effort to find the reason for the error yourself. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic), and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please also condense your code down to the expected [mre]. Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect. Remember to include _stack traces_ for your errors so that we know which line caused the error. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Helpful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: I have changed ```U[0] = U_0``` with ```U_0 = U.append(0)```. But now I have another error "IndexError: list index out of range" for ```L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])``` . I will appreciate for your help.

Comment: You're ignoring the useful comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have many errors in the for loops.
First in this for loop you have:

```
NmDef_value = []
for i in range(n):
    i +=1
    L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])
    print(i, L)
    NmDef_value.append(L)
```

In this code the foor loop is incrementing the i value by 1 on each step. In you case it is incrementing it by 1 and you are also incrementing it by 1 so on each iteration you are incrementing i by 2. When you will arrive at the last element of the list you will have `i = n` and you can only take the element of a list with the value n-1 or else you will get index out of range. You can fix it like that:

```
NmDef_value = []
for i in range(1,n):
    L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])
    print(i, L)
    NmDef_value.append(L)
```

For the second for loop:

```
for i in range (n):
    U[i]=U[i-1]+dt*(Fa[i]+Fr[i])
    V[i]=V[i-1]-dt*(Fa[i]+Fr[i])
    for i in range (n):
        print(U[i], V[i])
```

In this one for i = 0 you are trying to access U[i-1] so it is U[-1] and it will be out of range too. You can add a can start the for loop with 1 like that: `for i in range(1,n)`

Comment: Thank you very much. But still, there is the same error in the first loop ```    L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])

IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: I edited the response can you check it now?

Comment: Thank you Mario, But still shows the same error ```    L = NmDef(U[i], V[i], U[i-1], V[i-1])

IndexError: list index out of range```